# Solr exception: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=20

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, recovery

I'm getting the following exception against some solr queries in a multi-gigabyte Solr index. The whole index is built on Solr 3.5.0.

Does it means my index is corrupted? Then is there any way to recover it?

`HTTP Status 500 - docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=20 (got docID=2144084671) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=20 (got docID=2144084671) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.document(SegmentReader.java:475) at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.document(DirectoryReader.java:583) at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.document(SolrIndexReader.java:260) at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.doc(SolrIndexSearcher.java:452) at org.apache.solr.util.SolrPluginUtils.optimizePreFetchDocs(SolrPluginUtils.java:271) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.doPrefetch(QueryComponent.java:478) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:385) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)`

Comment: this happens roughly once every three times I run a query. Default query handler (/select?q=myQyery) works fine. The problem occurs with my own edismax query type (when I specify /select?qt=generic&q=myQuery), and that's why I think this should be a solr bug.

Comment: Generically speaking, an absolute doc id is being passed as a local, segment-relative doc id for a segment of 20 docs. Also, the number 2144084671 is getting dangerously close to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Maybe some overflow condition even.

Comment: Are you sure that doc id is bound to Integer.MAX_VALUE? Then any idea why this large docid is even generated? (is this generated from solr?)

Comment: I got the same problem when I am using Lucene. If this happens when searching, it is very likely you get some documents with negative scores. When you use indexreader to get the document id of this kind of docs, you will see the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Solr 3.6.0 and a full re-index solved this issue.